# Customer Specific Price

Tags: magento

Our management board wants to make customer specific price ( no discount ) for high volume customers. The price should same always when customer returns the store ( no one time).

As a result, discount or promotion mechanism of magento does not meet our necessity. So, what is the best way to make such a thing? If you have any sample, please be so kindly share with me? Thanks

Comment: Unless I misunderstand, it sounds like you are describing tier pricing, which is a core feature.

Comment: @Cags No, we can't use tier pricing. We don't need any reaction from customers. Those customers has a special status which they make a contract with us for time period then we just fix the product prices for them ( not all products, 100 of 2000 products ).

Answer (score 2):

Tiered pricing is going to be the best solution unless you consider developing/purchasing an extension for this.

You will have to assign customers to new customer groups and then apply tier pricing for each product accordingly. It will take time to set up and maintain, but this is the best bet without modification.

Answer (score 2):

We've contemplated adding this to our store, and the only way I can imagine it done(automatically) is using customer groups, and change their group once they reach a sales goal.

Comment: Dear @danchet, I know, we can do this way but we have aproximately 250.000 active customers on each stores! It's impossible at the moment. Also, as I mentioned, it's not necessary any reaction from customers ( I mean, buy 1000 product get %10 discount etc ). We would like to fix selected product prices for specific customers for a time period.